# Monotone function

Tags: real-analysis

If $f$ is a differentiable function on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f'(x)\ne0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, show that $f$ is monotone. You are not allowed to assume that $f'$ is continuous.

By the mean value theorem we have that $f(b)-f(a)=f'(c)(b-a)$ for a closed interval [a,b]. Also from Darboux's theorem, we have that there exists a number $k$ such that if $k$ is between $f'(a)$ and $f'(b)$, then there is at least one point c in $(a,b)$ such that $f'(c)=k$.

We have that $f'(c)\ne0$, so by the mean value theorem, $f(b)\ne f(a)$. If $f(b)>f(a)$ then there is a number $k$ such that $f(b)>f(c)=k>f(a)$ then since $f'(x)\ne 0$ for all $x$, $f$ can never retake the value of $k$.

Am I on the right track? I'm not sure how to continue.

Comment: Perhaps contradiction might be easier? Suppose the function is not monotone. How would you characterize that? Then use Rolle's theorem...

Comment: You're on the right track. Use Darboux' theorem to show that all $f'(x)$ have the same sign.

Comment: Do I show that they all have the same sign by doing many intervals? Like if $f(b)>f(a)$, then $f'(c)>0$. After that I take the interval $[c,b]$ and keep going?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that is not monotone. Restrict the function to a compact $[a,b]$. Since your function is not monotone, the maximum or minimun are attained at points other than the ends. Say $c\in (a,b)$ this point. For this because we have that $f'(c)=0$. A contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Derivatives have the mean-value property.  If a derivative assumes two values on an interval, it assumes all values in between. In the face of what you have here, you must have $f'(x) > 0$ for all $x$ or $f'(x) < 0$ for all $x$.

Comment: But we cannot assume that $f'$ is continuous, so we can't use the mean value theorem on $f'$

Comment: @Roshdy As ncmathsadist says, derivatives have the mean-value property, whether or not they're continuous.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I just realized that it is Darboux's theorem. But how am I supposed to show that? I'm not sure about the steps to take.